# Ionic using PayPal PlugIn vs Braintree

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, paypal, braintree, capacitor

I want to use PayPal in my hybrid Ionic App (Android and Apple). From the official PlugIn (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin):

> PayPal Mobile SDKs are Deprecated. The APIs powering them will remain
> operational long enough for merchants to migrate, but the SDKs
> themselves will no longer be updated. Please use Braintree Direct in
> supported countries.

Braintree says:

> The Braintree SDK is neither tested nor developed for hybrid runtimes
> such as Cordova, PhoneGap, Ionic, React Native, Electron, and Adobe
> AIR. While some success may be had in such environments, our SDK is
> optimized for the browser and its security policies and may not
> function correctly outside of them.

Both seem to work, but nothing should be used.
That seems to be a contradiction. So what should be used?

Comment: Any experiences someone?

Comment: I ended up in not using both of them.